# Windows form in c#, output the result

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, web-services, client

I trying to make a web service client to output some data. I was able to add the web service url and now I am trying to output the data. I have made this code but it doesn't display at all what I am looking (project names). Can you guys give me hand?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class DisplayDataInformation : Form
    {
        public DisplayDataInformation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            localhost.Dashboard proxy = new localhost.Dashboard();
            localhost.ProjectMetaData[] pm =  proxy.GetAllProjectMetaData();

            foreach (localhost.ProjectMetaData value in pm)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value);

            }

            //Console.ReadLine();                   
        }               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine` would produce the out in **[Output window in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/3hk6fby3.aspx)** in WinForms.

You can use a `Label` or `TextBox` control on the form to see the output on Form.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (localhost.ProjectMetaData value in pm)
{
    sb.Append(value.ToString());
}

label1.Text = sb.ToString(); //some label on your form for output
```

Comment: Hi, I have added a text box and still not showing anything private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            localhost.Dashboard proxy = new localhost.Dashboard();
            localhost.ProjectMetaData[] pm = proxy.GetAllProjectMetaData();

            foreach (localhost.ProjectMetaData value in pm)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value);
                //MessageBox.Show(pm);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

Comment: Why are you using `Console.ReadLine` and `Console.WriteLine`. The `Console.WriteLine` would produce the output in Visual studio output window, you can't see that on the Form.

Comment: ah ok I was doing all wrong, so With the example that you gave me in your answer, I can insert that into the text box method to output the result?

Comment: @user3790916, don't.. You are trying to modify contents of a `TextBox` in `TextChanged` event. Do it in a separate method like `Submit` in your case

Comment: when I do that I get the error, Cannont convert type "WindowsFormsApplication1.localhost.ProjectMetaData" to String.

Comment: @user3790916, call `value.ToString()`

Comment: Hi, it kind of work. When I execute the windows, I click on submit and the output now its "WindowsFormApplication1.local.ProjectMetaDataWindows" and it repeat it self several times, do you know whay I have this display....and thanks again in advance

Comment: I think its my foreach loop and it gets infinitive, but I dont know what else to include instead

Comment: @user3790916, your property `Value` points to an object which is using the default implementation of `ToString`, I am not sure about your object but may be you need Some property to display like `value.Name`

Comment: I have changed the foreach loop to this (foreach (localhost.ProjectMetaData value in pm)
            {
                sb.Append(value.ProjectID);
            }) and it dhow me eveything in one big line, how could separate all the project id?

Comment: @user3790916, use `sb.AppendLine(value.ProjectID);` this would display the result in each line

Comment: it worked!!! awesome!!! thanks a lot!! one last thing, if I put sb.AppendLine(value.ProjectTitle); for project titles and the rest of the infors in the same foreach this is going to work or its better to put it some where else?

Comment: @user3790916, you can do `sb.AppendLine(value.ProjectTitle + ",", value.ProjectID)`or use string.Format with place holders, its your choice

Comment: sorry to bother you again!, I have to include an APIKEY inside the code, because the web service require to enable the security. If I declare a apikey such as "string apiKey = "number";" how it can be called inside the foreach loop? thanks again

Comment: Not really sure about your new question but it should be as simple as `sb.AppendLine(value.ProjectTitle + ",", value.ProjectID + "," + apiKey)`

Comment: the problem is that the web service is was called correctly in the previous question. now the web service has an APIKEY activated that has to be inserted into the code to be able to display the same information but containing the APIKEY. I have inserted the option that you have me but it doesn't display anything sb.AppendLine(value.ProjectTitle + ","
                    + value.ProjectID + ","
                    + value.PublishStatus + "," + apiKey);